# Submit button refreshes the entire page while enter from keyboard

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, form-submit

I have this form, where i get input from user and insert it to table in the same form(inside td), i did it with js. Problem is whenever i click enter(using mouse) it works fine, but when i enter using keyboard it refreshes the entire page. what is the problem with the code?, How can i overcome it?

```
<form action="">
   LOAN AMOUNT:<input type="text" name="amount" id="amount"/>
   <input type="button" value="Enter" id="enter"/>
   <div class="CSSTableGenerator">
      <table>
         <tr>
            <th></th>
            <td></td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are using input type button so click event works fine on it but when you click enter key than form submit event take place because of that your page reload

you need to handle submit event instead of click event

make following changes in your html

```
    <form action="" id="myform" >

   <input type="submit" value="Enter" id="enter"/>
```

following in your js

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#myform").submit(function() { // handle submit instead of click 
            var p = document.getElementById("amount").value;
            var interest = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
            var year = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30];
            var r;
            var SI;
            var id;
            for (x = 0; x < interest.length; x++) {
                r = interest[x];
                id = x + 1;
                for (y = 0; y < year.length; y++) {
                    n = year[y];
                    SI = (p * n * r) / 100;

                    console.log(SI)
                    document.getElementById(n + "_year_" + id).innerHTML = SI;
                }
                console.log(p)
                console.log(r)
               document.getElementById("loan" + id).innerHTML = p;
                document.getElementById("interest" + id).innerHTML = r + "%";
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xumkjrao/)

Comment: Sorry i am not familiar with ajax; i had my javascript code in comment, how can i do it in ajax?, this code also stops loading but not getting user info. to my table

Comment: so where you want to get your form data after form submit ?

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){$("#enter").click(function(){ var p= document.getElementById("amount").value; var interest=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]; var year=[5,10,15,20,25,30]; var r; var SI; var id; for(x=0;x<interest.length;x++){ r=interest[x]; id=x+1; for(y=0;y<year.length;y++){ n=year[y]; SI=(p*n*r)/100; document.getElementById(n+"_year_"+id).innerHTML=SI; } document.getElementById("loan"+id).innerHTML=p; document.getElementById("interest"+id).innerHTML=r+"%"; } }); });`

Comment: Inside td, actually it is working fine using mouse click, but it won't work when i enter using keyboard.

Comment: Hurray it worked, i made like this, 
`function savevalues(){
  var p= document.getElementById("loan_amount").value;
     var interest=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
     var year=[5,10,15,20,25,30];
     var r;
     var SI;
     var id;
     for(x=0;x<interest.length;x++){
      r=interest[x];
      id=x+1;
      for(y=0;y<year.length;y++){
       n=year[y];
       SI=(p*n*r)/100;
     
     document.getElementById(n+"_year_"+id).innerHTML=SI;
      }
     document.getElementById("loan"+id).innerHTML=p;
     document.getElementById("interest"+id).innerHTML=r+"%";
     }`

Answer (score 1):

Handle `onsubmit`

Like this

```
<form action="" onsubmit="return false;">
```

Comment: it stops refreshing the page, but it won't take the user value inside table.

Comment: handle onclick on button id='enter' instead of onsubmit in js @santho

Comment: My js

`$(document).ready(function(){$("#enter").click(function(){
     var p= document.getElementById("amount").value;
     var interest=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
     var year=[5,10,15,20,25,30];
     var r;
     var SI;
     var id;
     for(x=0;x<interest.length;x++){
      r=interest[x];
      id=x+1;
      for(y=0;y<year.length;y++){
       n=year[y];
       SI=(p*n*r)/100;
     
     document.getElementById(n+"_year_"+id).innerHTML=SI;
      }
     document.getElementById("loan"+id).innerHTML=p;
     document.getElementById("interest"+id).innerHTML=r+"%";
     }
     
    });
   });`

Comment: it'll because it only stop form to submit other bubbling is ok @santho

Comment: @AnikIslamAbhi No i didn't, but hey i'll upvote it when the user marks it as an answer just to make sure your answer solves the issue!